# Node JS : how to fix validation failed cast to Array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i'm trying to make an API like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMyDr.png)

I tried to add a controller to the array, but I got a problem when I executed an error.

[error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6RnG.png)

I have been looking for a solution from google and stackoverflow for last post but I got confused with that.

I am very grateful for the help

this is my code from controller

```
getCommunity: async (req, res, next) => {

    const { playerId } = req.params;
    const newCommunity = new Community(req.body);
    //Get Player
    const player = Player.findById(playerId);
    // Assign player as a part of community's player
    newCommunity.communityPlayer = player;
    // Save the community
    await newCommunity.save();
    // Add community to the player's array
    player.PlayerCommunities.push(newCommunity);
    // Save the playerCommunities
    await player.save();
    res.status(201).json(newCommunity)
}
```

this from my model player

```
const playerSchema = new Schema({
  playerName: String,
  playerImage: { type: String, data: Buffer },
  playerNumberPhone: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return /\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{4}/.test(v);
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
    },
    required: [true, 'User phone number required']
  },
  playerAddress: String,
  PlayerCommunities: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'community'}]
});
```

this is my model community

```
const communitySchema = new Schema({
    communityName: String,
    communityImage: {type: String, data: Buffer},
    communityPlayer: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'player'}]
}, { usePushEach: true });
```

and this for my end point actually i using it

```
http://localhost:3000/player/:playerId/community
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you assign newCommunity play to the array is wrong that's why it screams the error. try like this

```
   getCommunity: async (req, res, next) => {

        const { playerId } = req.params;
        const newCommunity = new Community(req.body);
        //Get Player
        const player = Player.findById(playerId);
        // Assign player as a part of community's player
        newCommunity.communityPlayer.push(player); // here change your code like this
        // Save the community
        await newCommunity.save();
        // Add community to the player's array
        player.PlayerCommunities.push(newCommunity);
        // Save the playerCommunities
        await player.save();
        res.status(201).json(newCommunity)
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. it works, btw if i got problem like this again. what should i must learn before? if i want re-create my api maybe.. i'm new with programming.. thanks before

Answer (score 0):

In the community model communityPlayer property is an array.

But in the controller you are assigning a non-array value.

Change following line of your controller

```
newCommunity.communityPlayer = player;
```

To

```
newCommunity.communityPlayer.push(player);
```